# Como implementar Angular en Google App Engine

Tags: angular, google-app-engine

Este es mi archivo app.yaml

```
# [START runtime]
runtime: python27
threadsafe: yes
# [END runtime]
handlers:
- url: /(.+)
  static_files: dist/\1
  upload: dist/(.*)
- url: /
  static_files: dist/index.html
  upload: dist/index.html
skip_files:
- ^(?!dist)  # Skip any files not in the dist folder
```

El proyecto de Angular contiene la carpeta disp con los archivos del proyecto.

Estoy ejecutando gcloud app deploy desde el directorio donde se encuentra el archivo appl.yaml y me devuelve un error:ERROR: (gcloud.app.deploy) INTERNAL: Internal error encountered.

Alguien me ilumina?

Answer (score 0):

El problema estaba en la configuracion del comando gcloud.
Es necesario conocer que proyecto es el activo con
gcloud info

después cambiamos el proyecto con gcloud config set project NOMBRE PROYECTO CON ID

Y ha solucionado el error.